# How to set a resistance between two points by a digital input

Tags: arduino, digital-logic, resistors, integrated-circuit

For context, this is my first real delve into electronics.

For my current project, I need  that varies the resistance given input from an arduino.

What I was trying to do was, in conjunction with a voltage regulator, control the voltage going to a large LED array via arduino so the LED brightness can be set according to time of day.

In the comments below, it was noted that what I'm actually looking for in this application is an LED driver.

Comment: What are you trying to do? There are lots of ways to approach this problem.

Comment: In conjunction with a voltage regulator, control the voltage going to a large LED array via arduino so the LEd brightness can be set according to time of day.

Comment: In that case, unaccept Renan's answer. A digital pot is NOT what you want to control an LED array. The current draw will be too high. Edit your question to explain what you're actually trying to do and you'll get better answers. Include links to any relevant datasheets.

Comment: Agreed, you'll destroy any IC you use to control resistance this way.

Comment: You can certainly control LED brightness with a digital pot, given a suitable circuit. When a potentiometer is used as a control element, the load current does not have to pass through it. For example, the speaker current from an amplifier does not pass through the volume control.

Comment: Renan updated his answer in the comments section, I believe his response is still valid because of this.

Comment: Josh - yes it is, basically you need a multi-output LED driver with brightness control as he gives an example of. There are many types, with different ways of interfacing with the control pin (e.g. Analog, PWM, SPI, I2C, etc) Make sure you pick one which uses a method which suits you.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to control the LEDs via regulating voltage as opposed to using PWM dimming or by limiting current?

Comment: Because I didn't know those existed.  Also, for longevity's sake, I thought by keeping voltage lower when possible that it would be less likely to burn the LED's out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You likely want a [digital potentiometer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_potentiometer). In fact you can find [ready](http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/DigitalPotentiometer) [implementations](http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/SPIDigitalPot) for the Arduino.

But since you say you're driving a LED array, a digital pot won't cut it. You want something else, like a [TLC5940](http://www.ti.com/product/tlc5940) (which also [has an Arduino library](http://playground.arduino.cc/learning/TLC5940) available).

> The TLC5940 is a 16-channel, constant-current sink LED driver. Each channel has an individually adjustable 4096-step grayscale PWM brightness control and a 64-step, constant-current sink (dot correction).

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head, the things that come to mind are either using an EPOT, or running a current DAC "backwards".

> A digipot can be used as a variable resistor if one resistor end is connected to the wiper. Such digitally settable resistors are relatively inaccurate, however, because the total resistance of the digipot is subject to a manufacturing-dependent tolerance of 20% to 25%. In contrast, voltage-output DACs cannot be used as resistors. Current-output DACs can be used as variable resistors, but with the restriction that the DAC output must be connected to a virtual ground such as the summing node (inverting input) of an op amp.

[source](http://www.electronicproducts.com/Analog_Mixed_Signal_ICs/Standard_Linear/DAC_or_digital_pot.aspx)

Comment: That's fairly detailed!